# laravel- 404 not found but route exist

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to submit a form to update my table in the db and to test the controller is working, I made some test. I am learning how to pass data using POST method. This is my code.

**Route:**

```
Route::prefix('dashboard')->group(function () {
    // Route for panel.
    Route::prefix('panel')->group(function () {
        // Return index home page for panel.
        Route::get('/', 'Panel\DashboardController@index');
        // Update order information (delivery date and order status)
        Route::put('/update-order-information', 'Order\OrderController@update');
    });
}
```

**panel.blade.php (view):**

```
<table class="table table-light ">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Order ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Delivery Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Order Info</th>
        <th scope="col">Order Status</th>
        <th scope="col">Purchase Order</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($customerOrders as $customerOrder)
    <tr>
        <form action="/dashboard/panel/update-order-information/{{$customerOrder->order_id}}" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <td>{{$customerOrder->order_id}}</td>
            <td>
                <input name='delivery_date' class="date form-control" type="text" placeholder="Select delivery date"
                       autocomplete="off">
            </td>
            <td>{{$customerOrder->product_name}}</td>
            <td>
                <select id="status" name="status">
                    <option value="inProgress">In Progress</option>
                    <option value="shipped">Order Shipped</option>
                    <option value="cancelled">Cancelled</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>{{$customerOrder->purchase_order}}
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**OrderController.php:**

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $order = new Order();
    findOrFail($id);
    $order->order_id = $request->input('delivery_date');
    $order->order_status = $request->input('status');
    $order->save();
}
```

When I hit the submit button, it gives me a 404 page. Can anyone point out my mistake?

Comment: Instead of `Route::put(` try `Route::post(` since you are using post method on form and I think it should be giving you, method not allowed exception and not 404

Comment: @AkshayKhale Is my code logic correct?

Comment: Use the method suggested by Dilip in the answers, that's one of the most recommended way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `/` before your url like this

```php
<form action="/dashboard/panel/update-order-information/{{$customerOrder->id}}" method="POST" >
```

Edit:

```php
 /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $panel = Order::findOrFail($id)
        $panel->column_in_your_database = $request->input('delivery_date');
        $panel->save();
    }
```

Comment: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Order\OrderController::update(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected. New error

Comment: @LordJesus I updated my answer and added {{$customerOrder->id}} to fit your needs

Comment: How do I update the delivery date on my form to my table?

Comment: I mean it is possible that after i submit, it doesn't redirect my to another page but just get the id of the user and update the date?

Comment: With php you can't you need to use `ajax` here is an intro https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: So your way is better? Maybe i can add a redirect button to return to the previous page

Comment: Yes you can just `return back();`

Comment: what is request parameter for?

Comment: It’s a wrapper around all the data that came across with the HTTP request, such as headers, POST data, query string arguments, etc.

Comment: Okay I followed your method but it didn't send to the database table. Still show 404. Check my edited post

Comment: i am inside now

Answer (score 3):

Try to use URL in form action.

```
<form action="{{ url('dashboard/panel/update-order-information') }}" method="POST" > 
   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

Or else you can define [route name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes) as below.

```
Route::put('/update-order-information', 'Order\OrderController@update')->name('update.order');

<form action="{{ route('update.order') }}" method="POST" > 
   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

**Edit :-**

In your controller method, you're expecting `$id` but in URL you're not passing order id.

```
<form action="{{ route('update.order',['id'=>$customerOrder->order_id]) }}" method="POST" > 
   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

Route.php

```
Route::put('/update-order-information/{id}', 'Order\OrderController@update')->name('update.order');
```

Controller.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    dd("hello");
    // $panel = new Order();
    // $panel->order_id = $request->input('delivery_date');
}
```

Comment: I would recommend the [Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes)

Comment: it gives me this error now : Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Order\OrderController::update(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Comment: It because of here you're passing id as well remove it if you're not passing it in url.`public function update(Request $request, $id)`

Comment: I need to pass many order id because my table has many row with each order id that i can update the delivery date and order status.

Comment: So pass order id in array, remove `$id` from controller. in route file remove `{id}` and from url remove order id `['id'=>$customerOrder->order_id]`

Comment: Can you check my edited post? I made some changes but it's unable to pass to my table in d b